# Master page not working correctly in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have created a master page in my web app, but it is not working properly. The default page loads perfectly after successful login and I can browse to different links.

However when I browse to another page (could be any link), it loads but then nothing on the top nav and side nav works, the profile images disappears as well.

Example:

[image]

When I then browse to the "Consulting" page under "Client Reports", this then happens:

[image]

The links then on the side stop working (the drop down doesn't open) and clicking on dashboard says it can't find the page?

This is my code for the master file:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" 
    Inherits="FCAReportCentral.Master" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title><%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PageTitle"].ToString() %></title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/AdminLTE.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/gridView.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/Style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/morris.js/morris.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/util.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/main.css"/>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic"/>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <header class="main-header">
            <a href="index2.html" class="logo">
            </a>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
                </a>

                <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <img src="Resources/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                                <span class="hidden-xs">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="WelcomeBackMessage">Label</asp:Label></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="user-header">
                                    <img src="Resources/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                                    <p>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="WelcomeBackMessage1">Label</asp:Label>
                                    </p>
                                </li>
                                <li class="user-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                            <a href="#"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="user-footer">
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Profile</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">Sign out</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <aside class="main-sidebar">
            <section class="sidebar">
                <div class="user-panel">
                    <div class="pull-left image">
                        <img src="Resources/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left info">
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="WelcomeBackMessage2">Label</asp:Label></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
                    <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
                    <li class="active treeview">
                    <li><a href="~/Default.aspx">
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span>&nbsp;Dashboard</span>
                        <span class="pull-right-container"></span>
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-gear"></i><span>&nbsp;Administration</span>
                            <span class="pull-right-container">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">
                            <li><a href="Admin/Administration.aspx"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>User Registration</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Admin/Reporting.aspx"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Reports</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i><span>&nbsp;Client Reports</span>
                            <span class="pull-right-container">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">
                            <li><a href="Clients/Consulting/Consulting.aspx"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Consulting</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphSideNav" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </section>
        </aside>
        </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>Dashboard
                <small>Control panel</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Home</a></li>
                <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
            </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main Section -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBody" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="../Resources/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Resources/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Resources/js/MultiForm.js"></script>
<script>
    $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<script src="../../Resources/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/js/demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: How about if you try `src="~/Resources/..."`  instead of `src="Resources/..."` ?

Comment: Hi Thanks, have tried your suggestion but when the main loads it looks like the second image in my question.

Comment: I mean change `<img src="Resources/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">` to `<img src="~/Resources/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">`, did you try this?

Comment: Yes I have.  I don't know if the master page gets loaded twice??

Comment: Could you share sample page code as well? It is hard to understand by looking at just master page file